# how to merge together two queries in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 queries

Query 1: # of content pieces in a campaign

```
Select c.campaign_id, sum(case when medium in ('photo', 'story', 'video', 'album') then 1 else 0 end) as totalcontent
From `public_collaboration_contents` as cc 
Left join `public_collaborations` as c ON cc.collaboration_id = c.id
Left join `public_influencers` as i on c.influencer_id = i.id
Left join `public_collaboration_tasks` as ct on cc.id = ct.collaboration_content_id
Where cc.state = 'delivered'
And ct.state = 'delivered'
Group by c.campaign_id
```

Table looks like this:

| campaign_id | TotalContent |
| --- | --- |
| 1233 |  |

and

Query 2: campaign name, and Engagement rate

```
select c.campaign_id, brand_name,pc.title, (sum(psip.likes + psip.comments + psip.video_views)/sum(psip.influencer_starting_followers)) as ER FROM
`production.public_campaigns` as pc
LEFT JOIN `public_sponsored_instagram_posts` as psip
ON pc.id = psip.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN `public_instagram_post_performances` pipp
ON pipp.id=pc.id
LEFT JOIN `public_collaboration_contents`pcc 
on pcc.id=pc.id
LEFt JOIN `public_collaborations` as c 
ON c.id=pcc.collaboration_id
GROUP BY brand_name, title, campaign_id, pc.id
having (sum(psip.likes + psip.comments + psip.video_views)/sum(psip.influencer_starting_followers)) > 0
```

Table looks like this:

| Campaign_id | Brand_name | title | ER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1233 | asdf | asdf | 2% |

i'm hoping to join them together so my final table can look something like this:

| Brand_name | title | ER | TotalContent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| asdf | asdf | 2% | 50 |

how can i go about this? I tried to do joins with the two queries since they do pull from similar datasets, but i ended up getting the wrong TotalContent value (maybe i did the wrong join? but i tried all the joins and still didn't get the right number)

thank you SO much in advance for the help

EDIT #1:

the query i tried that gave me the wrong count is below (maybe i didn't do the joins right? i'm still very new to sql so could be that...)

```
select c.campaign_id, brand_name,pc.title, sum(case when medium in ('photo', 'story', 'video', 'album') then 1 else 0 end) as totalcontent, (sum(psip.likes + psip.comments + psip.video_views)/sum(psip.influencer_starting_followers)) as ER FROM
`production.public_campaigns` as pc
LEFT JOIN `public_sponsored_instagram_posts` as psip
ON pc.id = psip.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN `public_instagram_post_performances` pipp
ON pipp.id=pc.id
LEFT JOIN `public_collaboration_contents`pcc
on pcc.id=pc.id
LEFt JOIN `public_collaborations` as c
ON c.id=pcc.collaboration_id
GROUP BY brand_name, title, campaign_id, pc.id
having (sum(psip.likes + psip.comments + psip.video_views)/sum(psip.influencer_starting_followers)) > 0
```

Comment: Can you provide the query that you've tried already that gave the wrong count?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney sure thing, just added it to the question under EDIT #1